# Result of expression for a list

Tags: list, scheme

Why don't show result of expression?

```
(define a '((+ 1 5)(- 5 1)))
(define (ex) (car a))
(write ex)
```

Comment: what? what's the question? what language? what error?etc....

Comment: the return is "#<procedure:ex>" and don't the result of (+ 1 5).

Comment: which language is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling ex, try:

```
(write (ex))
```

if you wanted the result of evaluating (+ 1 5), you might need

```
(define a (list (+ 1 5) (- 5 1)))
```

Comment: perfect. however I can not move on the entry list.

Comment: If you meant that you can't edit the format of `a`, then perhaps `(write (eval (ex)))` does what you need?